# Multiple Choice and True/False Quiz using loops

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to build a quiz for a user that has to have 5 multiple choice questions and 5 true/false questions. I must do this using loops (while loops). I've come to the point where I set up a separate method asking the user the questions and error checking for the true/false or multiple choice questions. I now have to somehow give the user a point if they answer each question correctly. Then in the end, I must give the user the the total amount of points they won. Then I have to ask if they want to play again in the end, if they say yes I have to go back to the first question and restart the game and if they say no the program has to close. Here is where I got to on my main method. I started putting a while loop for the first answer (correct answer being 3) and making a point variable but I'm not sure where to go from there and how to connect everything. I hope what I did so far is correct. Thanks!

```
    UserInteraction input = new UserInteraction();
    Questions ask = new Questions();

    int answer1 = 0, answer2 = 0, answer3 = 0, answer4 = 0, answer5 = 0; 

    int a1 = ask.Question1(answer1);
    int point;

    while (a1==3)
    {point = 1;

    }

    int a2 = ask.Question2(answer2);
    int a3 = ask.Question3(answer3);
    int a4 = ask.Question4(answer4);
    int a5 = ask.Question5(answer5);


    boolean answer6=false, answer7=false, answer8=false, answer9=false, answer10=false;

    String a6 = ask.Question6(answer6);
    String a7 = ask.Question7(answer7);
    String a8 = ask.Question8(answer8);
    String a9 = ask.Question9(answer9);
    String a10 = ask.Question10(answer10);
```

For the Questions methods, I'll put two blank examples on here.

```
{public int Question1 (int answer1)
    {String message = "";
    int smallestValue = 1;
    int largestValue = 4;

    System.out.println("Q1) What is...?");
    System.out.println("1: ....");
    System.out.println("2: ......");
    System.out.println("3: ......");
    System.out.println("4: ......");
    System.out.print("Enter the number");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    UserInteraction input2 = new UserInteraction();

    answer1 = input2.getIntValueFromUserBetween(message, smallestValue, largestValue);
    return answer1;

}

public String Question6(boolean answer10)
    {String message = "";

    System.out.println("(Q10) ....(true/false)");
    System.out.print("Enter your answer here: ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    UserInteraction input2 = new UserInteraction();

    answer10 = input2.confirm(message);

    return "" + answer10;

}
}
```

Comment: Code for the Question method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if I misunderstand your question, but I don't understand why you're using a loop here.

```
while (a1==3)
```

Your program is either going to get stuck here or never use it. What I mean is that if the user answers the question correctly (i.e 3), they will be stuck in the while loop until you set a1 != 3.

What I think is a better solution is using selection. For example:

```
if (a1 == 3) {
     point += 1; // point = point + 1
     // Or whatever functionality you need here
}
```

Edit: If you really must use a loop, then having a Boolean flag would be the way to go. For example:

```
Boolean flag = false;    

if (a1 == 3) {
    flag = true;
    while (flag) {
        point += 1; //point = point + 1
        // Make sure that you set flag equals to false at the end of the loop though, otherwise it will infinitely loop
        // Include any other functionality needed
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know I didn't finish that part so I just put something to get started on it and set up the loop. I'm hoping there is a way to do it with loops rather than only using conditionals.

Comment: What is your reasoning behind wanting to use a loop? I don't really understand.

But it is possible. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Okay I may just need a loop to go back to the question if the user wants to play again. I'll try using both methods and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, you could have the entire process in a while loop. Similar to how I've used the Boolean flag. 

    Boolean flag = true;

    while (flag) {
        // Implement your code here
        // Check whether the user wishes to continue
        if (continue == "N") { 
             flag = false;
        }
    }

Comment: Just checking in to see how you went? Were you able to get it working?

Comment: Hi, yes I just got it to work now. Thanks for the help! (:

Comment: All good, glad to help .You should mark either Tom Collier's or my answer as correct depending on which one helped you solve your issue :) (That is if it was either of our answers that helped you solve the problem haha)

Answer (score 0):

Is this similar to what your looking for?

```
int correct;
public void quiz() { // this is so you can restart quiz easily
    String[] answers = String[5];
    //add answers to array, set them to variables/constant first then index
    String[] questions = String[5];
     // add questions to array
    for(int i = 0; i <= questions.length; i++) { // stops after all questions have been asked, make sure its "<="
        System.out.println(questions[i]); // prints question 1 first loop then 2 and so on
        // read input from user
        if(input == answers[i]) { // you may have to convert input to correct type
            correct += 1;
 }
}
}
 System.out.println("You got " + correct + " correct answers");
 System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
      if(input == yes) {
           quiz(); //starts quiz again // starts quiz method again
```

P.S. sorry if I've misunderstood the question

To ask different questions you can just change the String variables then call quiz() to ask those questions. nice and simple :)

Comment: also I'm sorry for being lazy and not adding input code and assignments etc. I've commented that all in for you! But it's easy stuff so you dont need me to put it in

Comment: Thanks! I got it working now.

Comment: That's great, you seemed confused at first with the first answer so thought I'd put this up as a second choice. Glad you got it working!